# Linux time and date

Tags: linux, time, amazon-ec2

I just create an instance in AWS amazon AMI .
And want to set the time and date.

I used this command.

```
date -s "20 NOV 2012 16:10:00"
```

but when I reboot, the date value is return to the beginning(before I changed)

what command should I used?

please help

Answer (score 2):

I think most likely your AMI is setup to automatically sync time by NTP and also at reboot.

Probably you have seen wrong time because of time zone that seemed wrong to you, such that you tried to "fix" the time.

Right solution would be use `tzselect` command to setup time zone that you prefer most.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the normal way to update the time (on physical hardware, without [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)) is:

1. date with relevant parameters to set time
2. Update hardware RTC with `# hwclock -w` (This is normal done by an init script when you shut down, but it is useful if you do not plan to shut down)

On Amazon, the hardware clock is likely read only (NTP might also be involved, but the virtualization usually synchronize the clock). VMWare have a clocksync option in the vmware-tools that keeps the OS clock in sync, the Xen linux kernel has [a setting to disable time sync](http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/4.0.1/guest/ch04s06.html).

Fixing the timezone is likely the solution you actually want, unless you want to deliberately set an incorrect time.

Comment: Ok I will Fixing the timezone . thanks for the reply.